# Possible to access a Glassfish/Eclipse database directly independent of Glassfish or Eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, derby

I've created a JEE6 web design using glassfish as the container and runtime enviornment, derby as the database and it's all managed in Eclipse. This is working great.

My question is how do I now access the database directly independent of Eclipse of Glassfish. Say I wanted another completely foreign program to have access (not through my controller--completely independent of Eclipse and Glassfish). How would I do this?

They seem so tightly integrated that I don't know if it's even possible.  I looked for the Derby installation through the file system and it is located inside of the Glassfish folders.

or what if I wanted to just update the database from a command line or linux terminal outside of Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the location of the Derby database of interest, you can simply write a standard JDBC application, include derby.jar in the classpath, register org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver with the DriverManager, and connect to the URL "jdbc:derby:/path/to/the/derby/database/directory".

Then away you go!

Comment: You can also, instead of writing your own JDBC app, use some existing Java-based DB explorers like [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/). Just add the JDBC driver and post it's connection data and off you go.

Comment: What do you suggest if my derby DB was created and then connected through Glassfish. I think the location is actually inside of the glassfish directory.  Where is the driver manager? Where do I find derby.jar?